# rugarch R: Volatility forecasts with 5 minute data problem

Tags: r, garch, large-data, volatility-forecasting

I am using the rugarch package in R to forecast volatility using 5 minute data. The package has an a conditional variance model exclusively written for high frequency data, the Multiplicative Component Garch, I know that. 
The thing is that I invested a whole month to to find tick data and transform them to 5 minute intervals which I then seasonally adjusted using techniques from the extant bibliography. 
I am trying to manipulate the package even though It is not efficient for 5 minute data to extract the conditional variance forecasts. My data span the period from 2015-01-01 17:00:00 to 2015-12-31 17:00. (I am willing to reduce my sample to find meaningful results).

This is how my data look like with five fivemin_returns[,2] being the standardised (deseasonalized) returns and [click this to download my data](https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B9Gcg5pCwYo6OERFMjg3SjNlaVU/view?usp=sharing)

```
head(fivemin_returns, 3)

                           DPRICE STD_DPRICE
2015-01-01 17:00:00  0.000000e+00  0.0000000
2015-01-01 17:05:00  9.797714e-05  0.2324451
2015-01-01 17:10:00  2.027022e-04  0.9845100

tail(fivemin_returns, 3)
                           DPRICE STD_DPRICE
2015-12-31 16:50:00 -0.0010186764 -6.0913134
2015-12-31 16:55:00 -0.0006841370 -3.9376338
2015-12-31 17:00:00  0.0002481227  1.1458867
```

So I want to create several conditional variance models and extract the forecasted sigma values. My methodology draws heavily from this article [Does anything NOT beat the GARCH(1,1)?](http://unstarched.net/2013/01/07/does-anything-not-beat-the-garch11/). I fit a MA(1) process to my returns without the conditional mean.

```
library(xts)
library(rugarch)
model = c('sGARCH', 'gjrGARCH', 'eGARCH', 'apARCH', 'csGARCH', 'fGARCH', 'fGARCH', 'fGARCH')
submodel = c(NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 'AVGARCH', 'NGARCH', 'NAGARCH')
spec1 = vector(mode = 'list', length = 8)
for (i in 1:8) spec1[[i]] = ugarchspec(mean.model = list(armaOrder = c(0, 1), include.mean = FALSE), variance.model = list(model = model[i], submodel = if (i > 5) submodel[i] else NULL))
spec2 = vector(mode = 'list', length = 8)
for (i in 1:8) spec2[[i]] = ugarchspec(mean.model = list(armaOrder = c(0, 1), include.mean = FALSE), variance.model = list(model = model[i], submodel = if (i > 5) submodel[i] else NULL), distribution = 'sstd')
spec3 = vector(mode = 'list', length = 8)
for (i in 1:8) spec3[[i]] = ugarchspec(mean.model = list(armaOrder = c(0, 1), include.mean = FALSE), variance.model = list(model = model[i], submodel = if (i > 5) submodel[i] else NULL), distribution = 'nig')
spec4 = vector(mode = 'list', length = 8)
for (i in 1:8) spec4[[i]] = ugarchspec(mean.model = list(armaOrder = c(0, 1), include.mean = FALSE), variance.model = list(model = model[i], submodel = if (i > 5) submodel[i] else NULL), distribution = 'jsu')
spec = c(spec1, spec2, spec3, spec4)
cluster = makePSOCKcluster(15)
clusterExport(cluster, c('spec', 'fivemin_returns'))
clusterEvalQ(cluster, library(rugarch))
# Out of sample estimation
n = length(spec)
fitlist = vector(mode = 'list', length = n)
for (i in 1:n) {
    tmp = ugarchroll(spec[[i]], fivemin_returns[,2], n.ahead = 1, forecast.length = 8640, refit.every = 50, refit.window = 'moving', windows.size = 1500, solver = 'hybrid', calculate.VaR = FALSE, cluster = cluster, keep.coef = FALSE)
    if (!is.null(tmp@model$noncidx)) {
        tmp = resume(tmp, solver = 'solnp', fit.control = list(scale = 1), solver.control = list(tol = 1e-07, delta = 1e-06), cluster = cluster)
        if (!is.null(tmp@model$noncidx))
            fitlist[[i]] = NA
    } else {
        fitlist[[i]] = as.data.frame(tmp, which = 'density')
    }
}
```

I tried to run the code but it is impossible due to the amount of data and the wrong formulation of the `ugarchroll(spec[[i]], R, n.ahead = 1, forecast.length = 8640, refit.every = 50, refit.window = 'moving', windows.size = 1500, solver = 'hybrid', calculate.VaR = FALSE, cluster = cluster, keep.coef = FALSE)` argument I reckon. I am not really sure about the

```
refit.every = 50, refit.window = 'moving', windows.size = 1500
```

How can I make it work? Decrease the sample size to 4 months maybe and try to forecast the last 15 days?

Edit 1: decreasing the sample and forecasting the condiational variance for the last 15 days is not the most practical thing to do as foreacting evaluation techniques with 15 (aggregated) observations is not a sensible thing to do. That is why I see at least one year of tick data in other papers and makes me think how much computing power have these scientists at their disposal? With my mere I3 processor and 4 gb ram I can't do anything.